# Convert date to string for automated directory searching

Tags: excel, vba, string, date

My ultimate goal is to be able to search a file path, where another user will be creating a new folder each month (for example next month the user will create the folder "January 2022"), and I need to be able to search for that folder in an automated way based on the current month and year.

My plan is to create a string object like so:

```
Dim strDirectory As String
strDirectory = "C:\foo\bar\baz\" & strCurrentMonthName & " " & strCurrentYear
```

But, I'm having trouble extracting the year as text. Originally I tried to do this:

```
Dim TestMonth As String
Dim TestYear As String

TestYear = Year(Now)
TestMonth = GetMonthName(Format(Now, "mm"))
```

Problem is that `testYear` gets returned as 7/13/1905. [This webpage](http://keyliner.blogspot.com/2014/08/solution-excel-yyyy-dates-show-as-1905.html) shows how to fix this error in a spreadsheet, but that's not going to help my situation as the date will never be pulled from a spreadsheet (as I feel that's a very error-prone way to do things). The Year function supposedly only works on Variant, Numeric, or String expressions and I don't know how to get just the year from `Now`.

Keep in mind that my ability to access standard libraries is very limited, I'm using an older version of Excel (2016) and have no control over packages or updates (there are certain features I've had to do without such as MonthName() for example, I had to create my own version of that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008925);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) returns a **Variant (String)** containing an expression formatted according to instructions contained in a format expression.

So whatever format you express in `Format` will be returned as a string.

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim CurrentDate As Date
    CurrentDate = Date
    
    Dim strDirectory As String
    strDirectory = "C:\foo\bar\baz\" & Format(CurrentDate, "mmm yy") '"C:\foo\bar\baz\Dec 21"
    strDirectory = "C:\foo\bar\baz\" & Format(CurrentDate, "mmmm yyyy") '"C:\foo\bar\baz\December 2021"

End Sub
```

No need for a `GetMonthName` function - `Format(Now(),"mmmm")` returns December this month.

Comment: This worked, but I don't understand why. When you declare ```CurrentDate = Date```, shouldn't that throw an error? If I typed ```Dim myString As String     myString = String``` I wouldn't expect that to work either

Comment: No, it doesn't throw an error as I declare `CurrentDate` as the [Date data type](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/date-data-type) and use the [Date function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/date-function) to return the current system date.  The word Date is used in two different contexts - as a data type and as a way to return the current system date.  Your example would work if you used `Dim MyString As String: MyString = "String"` - I've declared it as a string and put the word string in it.

Comment: I suppose I was confused because of the double meaning. I was trying to use ```Now``` when I should have been using ```Date```. Thank you!

Comment: I guess you could use `Now()` - it's just the date with the time stuck on (as a number Date is the whole number, time is the fraction of a number).  So 12.5 would be midday on day 12 (day 12 being 12th Jan 1900), 12.25 would be 6am, 12.75 would be 6pm.

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out:

```
Dim TestMonth As String
Dim TestYear As Date



testYear = Now
TestMonth = GetMonthName(Format(Now, "mm"))

Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "C:\foo\bar\baz\" & TestMonth & " " & Year(TestYear)
```

Output:

```
C:\foo\bar\baz\December 2021
```

Comment: You should choose the direct method as posted by @Darren.